# Message bundles in JSF

Tags: jsf, internationalization

I am using JSF and I want to use message bundles so I added the XML configuration below. Now I wonder if someone could write some experiences they had when using them. Is it best practice to have one big properties file that contain all translation on the page, if so how do you name your keys. If not, then I guess you have multiple resource files, how do you structure them - what part of the page do they provide messages for? - and any naming practices?

I know this may be subjective but it could be valuable insights for me anyway.

```
<application>
    <resource-bundle>
        <base-name>com.myapp.blah</base-name>
        <var>msgs</var>
    </resource-bundle>
</application>
```

Comment: for what it is worth I think you're heading for a lot of opinion. I generally shy away from the "huge file" and stick with one per module/component etc... It is tedious, but if you have the time it is a better way to internationalize. Also, it avoids the problem of key-name collisions. Generally I keep track of it per bean as I generally have some sort of view logic per-page.

Comment: This is very similar to a question I asked a while ago. The answer there may be helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414313/how-to-organize-java-properties-entries-for-internationalization

Comment: @digitaljoel Thanks, did not spot that question. I guess what I am currently doing is the state of the art then. May I ask what you did with the actual content of the page? Like how do you translate the content inside <p> tags for instance? Right now I have only target what I would call the "guide" text such as navigation links etc.

Comment: I didn't have any really large content spaces in my page.  Most of our i18n work was with tab names, button text, headers, that kind of thing, but there's no reason you can't just use a bundle key for an entire paragraph of content. The question then becomes do you break the key on each bit of markup? That sounds kind of stinky to me, but leaving markup in the i18n value also sounds stinky. Unfortunately, I don't have any great advice for you in this area. I'm more of a "make it go" kind of person, and leave the design to the designers. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you begin with the single File approach, one per language. If it grows in a level that you simply can't manage anymore, thousands of lines, than you might split it.

Then you can internationalize your pages using a template that will have:

```
<f:view locale="#{userBean.userLocale}">
```

and you can enable a select component to hold the available languages for the users to switch:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().setLocale(locale);
```

and in faces-config.xml:

```
    <application>        
        <locale-config>            
            <default-locale>pt-br</default-locale>
            <supported-locale>en</supported-locale>            
        </locale-config>

        <resource-bundle>
            <base-name>com.myapp.blah.ApplicationResources</base-name>
            <var>msg</var>
        </resource-bundle>
...
```

then you shall have one file per language:

ApplicationResources.properties
ApplicationResources_en.properties
ApplicationResources_pt_BR.properties